# Starting sentence with "indeed" to complete previous statement

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, sentence-starts

Is it correct to add a sentence that starts with *indeed* in order to complete a previous statement? For example,

> The political crisis has a negative influence on the economy.
>   **Indeed**, foreign investments have never been as low.

Is it recommended to start a sentence with *indeed* in a research paper?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Yes, the sentence is OK. The meaning is something like this:

> The political crisis has a negative influence on the economy. **You can see that this is true, because, for example**, foreign investments have never been as low.

> Is it recommended to start a sentence with "indeed" in a research paper?

I don't think "recommended" is the right choice of words—that makes it sound like you should use it whether or not it is called for—but it should be acceptable.

Answer (score 19):

Indeed you can. :-)

Comment: Indeedly doodly.

Comment: But what about starting sentences with a conjunction?

Comment: Or without a verb?

Answer (score 1):

"Indeed" can start a sentence as either a conjunction or an interjection.

As a conjunction, *indeed* provides emphasis or indicates that the sentence is an example of, or evidence for, a claim made in the previous sentence.

As an interjection, *indeed* indicates surprise or sarcastic doubt. In this use, *indeed* is often the only word in the sentence. `He thinks she'll marry him? Indeed!`

In formal writing, the use as a conjunction, to mean the same thing as "for example" is perfectly acceptable. That was precisely the way you used it. Just don't use it too often or it gets tedious. If "for example" is starting to get tedious, switch it up with an "indeed".