# The use of indeed at the begining of a paragraph

Tags: word-choice, writing-advice

Is it appropriate to use indeed at the beginning of a paragraph? 
I have two paragraphs as follows: 
Paragraph "A" describing some concepts that are better to be considered in a class of methods, name it M. 
Paragraph "B" discussing that in fact these concepts are considered in some literature related M.
In fact, the two paragraphs should be combined in the following manner "A. Indeed, B". However, the resulting paragraph is too big. 
As in writing different paragraphs should be independent, the use of indeed at the beginning of a paragraph seems to be inappropriate?

Comment: Hello, Reza. This hinges solely on writing style, not on grammaticality, correct choice of word etc. As such, it's off-topic here on ELU. 'Indeed' _is_ used to develop a topic rather than to move on to fresh material, but one can get too legalistic about conforming to a set pattern. If the paragraph would be too big and 'indeed' is the best choice of word from a semantic viewpoint (_are you sure it is!?_), I'd go with it. Who's going to censure us? An editor or tutor? (I've got beyond the stage where they exist, but you may have to do their bidding. Life's like that.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks Edwin, yes I think it is the best choice. But, I don't think the editor would that ;)

Comment: It's absolutely okay to begin a sentence, even a paragraph, with the introductory conjunction *indeed*.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2754/14666

Comment: Would 'moreover' wrong-foot the editor?